# Why does fresh zinc oxide cause chills but "old oxide" does not?

Tags: respiration

Inhalation of fresh zinc oxide causes chills; aka- zinc chills, brass founders ague, oxide shakes, etc. But if the oxide is a few hours old it will not cause chills. I had them once long ago, an old experience person explained the situation which I had never heard of. Pollution controls and modern safety practice have made it very rare in the US today. It can occur if one inadvertently causes a "zinc boil" by overheating a brass melt or oxy-acetylene cutting galvanized steel, etc.

Comment: Can you include a reference to something besides your personal experience? It seems very unlikely to me that anything here is involving the "fresh"ness of anything; it sounds like you're talking about a situation where there are inhalable metal oxides present compared to a situation where there are not inhalable metal oxides present. In that case the "why" is a bit boringly obvious, is it not? Can you clarify your question to make it more clear where the uncertainty lies?

Comment: I'd wager that your "old zinc oxide" is nothing more than rough-powdered whereas the irritant stuff from welding is nanometre-sized and finely dispersed in air (from experience and observation).

Comment: this is possibly because fresh zinc in the air is not fully oxidized and the old zinc in the air are.maybe you can ask a related question over at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ and link to this one.

Comment: Is what you're describing the same as [metal fume fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_fume_fever)?  [This article](http://www.inaactamedica.org/archives/2014/25348190.pdf) describes it and says the particle size should be under 1 micron for acute systemic effects, and also says that aggregation of these particles occurs.  Do you know whether the old oxide you describe clumps up into larger particles?

Comment: Note the reference states "freshly formed" zinc oxide. Also, Zinc oxide is produced by mixing hot zinc vapor ( very small particles) with air. Wikipedia article not accurate ; i am looking for the book reference.